JPQL issue on update query based on child entity value
The query is
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE Record r " +
        "SET r.blockedToConvert = true " +
        "WHERE r.cliente.documento = :documento " +
        "AND r.moment < :time")
void blockToConversionBeforeDateTime(String documento, LocalDateTime time);

Where on Record entity:
@ManyToOne
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
@JsonBackReference
@JoinColumn(name="cliente_kanban_id")
private ClientesKanBanEntidade cliente;

where ClientesKanBanEntidade contains an entity property called 'documento' which is also the database column name on regarding table for this entity.
The problem is JPQL translate its query to:
UPDATE records__users_made_contacts 
SET blocked_to_conversion=1 
WHERE documento=? and moment<?

as column 'documento' were in records__users_made_contacts table but it should translate the query as something like:
UPDATE records__users_made_contacts r
JOIN clientes_kanban c
SET r.blocked_to_conversion=1 
WHERE c.documento=? and r.moment<?

Is it possible on JPQL update a parent entity based on a NON-ID property form a child entity?

r.cliente.documento = :documento - rewrite the using in or exists: r.cliente in (select c from ClientesKanBanEntidade c where c.documento = :documento)

Why for SELECT filtering by child entity works well but on UPDATE clause does not

the problem is the syntax you expect to work is not ansi-compliant, so, JPA provider would need to rewrite such JPQL to SQL update compatible with particular DB, nobody has implemented that yet.
